# I can not click my checkbox within my datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a unique case in my WPF application. I have a data model which is being used in an observable collection. This is my data model:

```
public PetRowInformation : ViewModelBase
{
   public bool IsSelected
   {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
             _isSelected = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
        }
   }
   private bool _isSelected = false;

   public Pet Pet {get;}
}
```

In my main view model I have:

```
public PetTableViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<PetRowInformation> PetInfoCollection
    {
        get => _petInfoCollection;
        set
        {
            if (_petInfoCollection != value)
            {
                _petInfoCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PetInfoCollection));
            }
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<PetRowInformation> _petInfoCollection = new ObservableCollection<PetRowInformation>();

    public PetRowInformation SelectedPetRow
    {
        get => _selectedPetRow;
        set
        {
            _selectedPetRow= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPetRow));
        }
    }
    private PetRowInformation _selectedPetRow;

    // Constructors and other methods below...
}
```

Finally, in my Xaml I have:

```
<DataGrid
                ItemsSource="{Binding PetInfoCollection}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPetRow, Mode=TwoWay}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                BorderThickness="1"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                ColumnHeaderHeight="30"
                IsReadOnly="True" 
                RowHeaderWidth="0"
                RowStyle="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pet Station">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <CheckBox Margin="8,5,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" 
                                              IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Pet.StationString}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--Other Columns Below-->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

For the most part everything works great, I see the data updating. But what I can't seem to get it to work is the IsSelected Property. When I click on the checkbox nothing happens. The binding is not working and I'm not even able to leave a checkmark on it. It always stays unchecked which I find weird. Can anyone help me understand why my check box is not working? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested the binding and it worked on the `IsSelected` property. Does your checkbox visually resond to hovering over it?

Comment: @thatguy not, it has no on hover trigger to it.

Comment: Can you show your `DefaultRowStyle`?

Comment: @thatguy that was it! DefaultRowStyle was managing how the rows got enabled. Thank you, your question helped.